# sqlalchemy.orm.subquery does not seem to load only specific columns

Tags: sqlalchemy

how can i load only specific columns when using subquery?

It seems like subquery loads all the columns from the table even though I included load_only option before calling subquery.

Code snippet is

```
results = session.query(User).options(load_only(User.name, User.fullname))
results = results.subquery()
```

The first result statement only loads name and fullname from User but the second result statement loads all the columns.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. It works if i do

```
results = session.query(User.name, User.fullname)
results = results.subquery()
```

Not sure if anynone has a better solution?